# Handling VMCALL with libvirt (qemu-kvm)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I am using libvirt with qemu-kvm to manage virtual machines. The guest makes a vmcall which I want to be notified of, e.g. via a callback function. I know it's possible with 'pure' KVM, but does the libvirt API provide functions to handle a vmcall (or other vm exits)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'vmcall' is a low level instruction for a guest to trap into the hypervisor and as such will always be handled by KVM and/or QEMU. It is not visible to mgmt software like libvirt or anything above that. If you want the guest to interact with mgmt software on the host it is better to use a higher level communications channel. Assuming networking is not an option, then virtio-serial provides a simple stream for apps to use. This is what guest services like the QEMU guest agent, and SPICE agent use to talk to the host.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. Are the virtio-serial ports secure tough? But yes you are correct, I need a way to talk to the host.

Comment: Anyways I am using virtio now. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: A virtio-serial device is secure - only the guest to which it is assigned can use it, and of course the host. Nothing off-host, nor other guests can see it. So to snoop on it you would have to be root in the host, which is already a privileged account.